# Slow performance toLocaleString() Node.js update from 12.18.3 to 18.13.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, service

We have recently updated node.js from version 12.18.3 to version 18.13.0. We run node.js on windows.

We experience a problem with the built-in function `toLocaleString()` and the problem is that it takes about 10x the time that it used to take earlier. The problem only occurs when we start our API as a service. If it's started in the command prompt and we shoot requests against it, the function's performance is as fast as it where earlier.

We have a function called `strDateArr(fd, td)` where we can send in a `fromdate` and `todate` and the function returns an array with string formatted dates. Example,

```js
let dates = strDateArr("2013-01-31", "2022-12-31")
```

returns,

`["2013-01-31", ..., "2022-12-31"]`

The usage of `toLocaleString()` in our function looks like this.

```js
let relDateStr = relDate.toLocaleString("sv-SE", {
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric",
  day: "2-digit",
});
```

This might be a cache problem and I really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with that particular function and not because it is run as a service?

Comment: So the problem occurs when it runs as a service and it occurs in this function and that is what i need help with. When i run ```npm start``` from cmd in project directory on server it works as intended.

Comment: Could you please provide details about how you're measuring the speed and perhaps how it is setup as a service?

Comment: It is an api so only backend code.

Comment: I narrowed it down to that function and then measuring time by putting t1 = Date.now() before the function and t2 = Date.now() after and looking at (t2-t1). The service was installed by running this function,

Comment: ```async install() {
  try {
    // Create a new service object
    var svc = new Service({
      name: "our service name",
      script: "full filepath to server.mjs",
      description: "description"
    });
    let installPromise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      try {
        svc.on('install',() => {
          resolve("Service Installed")
        });
        svc.on('error', (err) => {
          reject(err)
        });
           svc.install();
      }
      catch(err) {
        reject(err)
      };
    })```

Comment: const Service = require('node-windows').Service;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` with its `format()` method when you want to format large numbers of dates. It usually is faster:

```js
let formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('sv-SE', {
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric",
  day: "2-digit"
});

let relDateStr = formatter.format(relDate);
```

You can run the snippet below for a quick and dirty benchmark:

```js
let dates = [];
let options = {
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric",
  day: "2-digit"
};

for (let i = 0; i < 20 * 365; i++)
  dates.push(new Date(Date.now() - i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

let t0 = performance.now();

dates.map(date => date.toLocaleString("sv-SE", options));

let t1 = performance.now();
let formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('sv-SE', options);

dates.map(date => formatter.format(date));

const t2 = performance.now();
console.log(`toLocaleString() took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);
console.log(`Intl.DateTimeFormat() took ${t2 - t1} milliseconds.`);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That solved my problem perfectly. This was one of the weirdest issues ever. Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: Here's an article explaining why this works: https://nedwize.hashnode.dev/tolocalestring-is-too-slow-heres-how-to-improve-it